# jquerymobile and android back button

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to know if there is a way to know when the user presses the "back" button in android, and in which page he does so?

I'm asking because i want to control the user pages order. now i'm doing that by adding a "back" button in the header of each page, but if the user presses the  "back" button in android smartphones i have no control on the pages flow order.

For example if the user presses the back button on the first page, he immediately exit the application, and i can't alert him if he really wants to exit.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put an general event with Phonegap backbutton listener after ondeviceready:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Inside yourCallBackFunction you can evaluate the page id with `$.mobile.activePage.attr('id')` so you known the current page and jump accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the 'beforeunload'?

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    ...
});​
```